# PHP Laravel, а точнее @component

Tags: php, laravel

Появилась проблема, вовремя обучения Laravel у меня появилась проблема которую не могу разобрать, прошу посмотреть: `

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app_admin')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
        @component('admin.components.breadcrumb')
            @slot('title') Список категорий @endslot
            @slot('parent') Главная @endslot
            @slot('active') Категории @endslot
        @endcomponent
        <hr>

        <a href="{{route('admin.category.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Создать категорию
        </a>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th>Наименование</th>
                <th>Публикация</th>
                <th class="text-right">Действие</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @forelse ($categories as $category)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$category->title}}</td>
                        <td>{{$category->published}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{route('admin.category.edit',['id'=>$category->id])}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                @empty
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="text-center"><h2>Данные отсутствуют</h2></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforelse
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

`

иии вот: `

```
<h2>{{$title}}}</h2>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="{{route('admin.index')}}">{{$parent}}</a></li>
    <li class="active">{{$active}}</li>
</ol>
```

`

А на выходе получаю вот это: "@component('admin.components.breadcrumb') @slot('title') Список категорий @endslot @slot('parent') Главная @endslot @slot('active') Категории @endslot @endcomponent", пытался найти в интернете но ничего нет, есть какие то идеи?